# How do I add an entry in an array inside MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, async-await

Below is my code to add an item to an array inside a mongoDB object. I am trying to add a review for my restaurant

The restaurant object looks like:

```
_id: ObjectID("61723c7378b6d3a5a02d908e")
name: "Hotel"
reviews: Array
```

reviews.js:

```
const mongoCollections = require('../config/mongoCollections');
const restaurants = mongoCollections.restaurants;


module.exports = {

  async created (restaurantId, title, reviewer, rating, dateOfReview, review) {
    
    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    let newReview = {
      restaurantId : restaurantId,
      title : title,
      reviewer : reviewer,
      rating : rating,
      dateOfReview : dateOfReview,
      review : review
    };

    const insertInfo = await restaurantsCollection.updateOne( {_id : restaurantId},{$addToSet: {reviews: newReview}} )
    
    if (insertInfo.insertedCount === 0) throw 'Could not add review';
 
  },
```

index.js:

```
const restaurantsData = require('./restaurants');
const reviewsData = require('./reviews')

module.exports = {
  restaurants: restaurantsData,
  reviews: reviewsData
};
```

seed.js: // to call the function

```
const dbConnection = require('../config/mongoConnection');
const data = require('../data/');
const restaurants = data.restaurants;
const reviews = data.reviews;

const main = async () => {
    await reviews.created("61723c7378b6d3a5a02d908e", "random", "sam", 4, "25/2/2002", 
    "amazing");
      
}

main();
```

I tried to use update instead of updateOne but it shows a deprecated warning

Comment: did you tied passing _id as a ObjectId for updateOne?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean

Comment: await reviews.created(new ObjectID("61723c7378b6d3a5a02d908e"), "random", "sam", 4,"25/2/2002",  "amazing"); I was wondering Are you passing String ID vs ObjectID ,so update is not working